# Concatenate Object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

I have a JavaScript Object and I'm sure the value of any key is an array (even empty in some case):

```
{key1:["a","b","c"],key2:["d","e","f"],key3:...}
```

Aside from using Underscore, is there any way to concatenate all the values of this Object (and create a new array)?

At the moment I get the keys name using `Object.keys`, then I loop and concatenate.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: It's fine but I was looking for something more "compact"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```js
var obj = {key1:["a","b","c"],key2:["d","e","f"]};

var arr = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(res, v) {
    return res.concat(obj[v]);
}, []);

// ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Comment: Beware that even though, personally, I love these functional approaches, many people will be confused by this method.

Comment: ...or simply `[].concat.apply([], values)`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: why confused?

Comment: Because there are people that get confused with a functional language approach; it's outside of many programmers' comfort zones. Remember that you should code in a way that eases future maintenance efforts and clever approaches like this may hinder understanding where the simple loop and concatenate may not.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I find functional approach more preferable; it became "common ground" for different languages of very high level. As a example, answer code, rewritten with `for`, is limited to JavaScript, programmer should know specific JavaScript language constructions (should we use `for` like C or we can use `for in` or something like that, should we use parentheses). Functional way is more simple, programmer should know functions and some APIs (which are becoming more and more unified between different languages).

Comment: @Philogenesis: that's true but I generally comment my code... And: does a programmer really need such a "comfort zone"? I like to explore new functions... The only thing that could avoid me to use Aliaksei function could be performance issues (but in my case this is not a problem, I can have Objects with less then 10 keys)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I upvoted the answer because I like this approach. But, sometimes you have to be pragmatic and realise that a functional approach requires a certain level of intuition that, sadly, is not always there.

Answer (score 14):

#### A simple approach is to get the values using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) them with `[].concat.apply()` in this way:

```js
const _obj = { key1:["a","b","c"], key2:["d","e","f"], key3:["g","h","i"] }

const _arr = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(_obj))

console.log(_arr)
```

---

#### Another *similar way*, is to *merge* [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) them into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) like this:

```js
const _obj = { key1:["a","b","c"], key2:["d","e","f"], key3:["g","h","i"] }

const _arr = [].concat(...Object.values(_obj))

console.log(_arr)
```

---

#### Also [reducing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) each value of the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) them, you can get the same result:

```js
const _obj = { key1:["a","b","c"], key2:["d","e","f"], key3:["g","h","i"] }

const _arr = Object.values(_obj).reduce((r,c) => r.concat(c), [])

console.log(_arr)
```

---

#### To finish, you can also use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) over each value of the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). Just keep in mind: it's not supported on all browsers.

```js
const _obj = { key1:["a","b","c"], key2:["d","e","f"], key3:["g","h","i"] }

const _arr = Object.values(_obj).flat()

console.log(_arr)
```

Hope this methods could help someone out there :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the [array concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) function

```
var obj = {key1:["a","b","c"],key2:["d","e","f"],key3:["g","h"]};

var resultArray = [];
for (var key in obj) resultArray = resultArray.concat(obj[key]);

alert(resultArray);
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qpLq11ea/

Comment: This is very similar to my current solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/6hbp5bzo/

```
var arr= [];
var o={key1:["a","b","c"],key2:["d","e","f"]}
for(key in o){
  if(o.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    arr.push(o[key]);
}
}
alert(arr);
```