# Javascript : Concatenate object values in a variable

Tags: javascript, object, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate values from "seller" Key in a new variables "sellerList" but I'm not achieving to find a good solution.

```
const data = {
  page: {},
  product: {
    attributes: {
      condition: 'used',
      offer: {
        offer1: {
          condition: 'used',
          offerID: '1111',
          seller: 'Ben',
          sellerID: 'abc',
        },
        offer2: {
          condition: 'used',
          offerID: '2222',
          seller: 'manu',
          sellerID: 'def',
        },
        offer3: {
          condition: 'used',
          offerID: '3333',
          seller: 'Ben',
          sellerID: 'abc',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187204/concatenate-a-key-value-from-a-object-in-javascript) which has a similar issue, but it's not working on my side

As we can't use map method on object, I pushed my object into an array like this:

```
dataArr = [];
dataArr.push(data);
```

Then I used the following code to concatenate:

```
const sellersList = Object.keys(digitalData)
  .map((o) => o.seller)
  .join(';');

console.log('Offer list :' + sellersList);
```

But this returns an empty string: "Offer list :;"

So my goal is to have a final string like this : "ben;manu;ben"

Does anyone have an idea how to arrange the code fit with my case ?
Thank you for your help and your time.

Comment: `Object.values(data.product.attributes.offer).map(e=>e.seller).join(";")`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the data shape that you shared, you can do it like that:

```
Object.values(data.product.attributes.offer)
      .map(offer => offer.seller)
      .join(';')
```

Comment: That definitely fixed my case ! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. It does rely on your data having this specific shape with those precise key names - but it's not clear what else you can do as I don't know the details of where your data comes from and what else it might look like. Hope this helps give you a start, anyway!

```js
const data = {
        page: {},
        product: {
          attributes: {
            condition: "used",
            offer: {
              offer1: {
                condition: "used",
                offerID: "1111",
                seller: "Ben",
                sellerID: "abc",
              },
              offer2: {
                condition: "used",
                offerID: "2222",
                seller: "manu",
                sellerID: "def",
              },
              offer3: {
                condition: "used",
                offerID: "3333",
                seller: "Ben",
                sellerID: "abc",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      };

const result = Object.values(data.product.attributes.offer).map(offer => offer.seller).join(";");
console.log(result);
```